# Java vs. JavaScript variable scope

Tags: java, javascript, scope

In the following Java snippet, the scope of `i` is limited to the inside of the `for` loop. That's why it causes an error. However, in the similar JS snippet, the `i` is apparently accessible outside of the loop. How is that possible?

Java:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    ...
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Output: "i is not defined"

JS:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) { 
    ...
}
console.log(i);
```

Output: 10

I didn't expect to see output from the JS. I want to know how JS differs from Java. How does JavaScript variable scope work?

Comment: Did you _mean_ to have the semicolon at the end of the `for`?

Comment: I think he did, otherwise the result of the first loop would be ten prints and not "i is not defined".

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes, he meant to leave the semicolon there.  The fact you had to check is why doing so is _never_ good practise.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've edited the question so that this confusion may be avoided.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Javascript "local" variables have *function scope*, not *block scope*.

All local variable declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the current scope, so your code is equivalent to:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
}
console.log(i);
```

Note that while the *declaration* is hoisted, any *assignment* is not.  e.g. this code

```
function test() {
    console.log(i);  // undefined
    var i = 1;       // declaration and assignment
    console.log(i);  // 1
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function test() {
    var i;           // declaration hoisted
    console.log(i);  // undefined
    i = 1;           // assignment still happens here
    console.log(i);  // 1
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that, since all variable declarations will be hoisted to the top of the function they appear in, many (myself included) consider it best practice to reflect that in the code by declaring all variables at the start of the function, even if they are only used in one block. This prevents confusion and also makes it easier to sort out closures.

Comment: @Kiyura actually, I don't adhere to that view, I prefer to declare (and assign to) variables closer to their point of use.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript only has two types of scoping - global and functional. Javascript is [lexically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping_and_dynamic_scoping) at the function-level.