# Asynchronous javascript issue, appends undefined to page even though network has response

Tags: php, jquery, settimeout

I am having an issue with the values obtained from an ajax call attempting to append to the page before the value is actually assigned. For example, when sendRequest below is called I am getting a price response from the network each time, but when I console.log it, sometimes I get undefined. See comments in bold. I have tried making ajax request synchronous and a really ghetto setTimeout function, but I still get the occassional undefined. How can I make sure the price gets appended to the page? Please be nice to me if I'm being slow today :D

```
function updatePrices(IDs,callback){
    var product_id= <?=$product_id ?>;
    var qty= parseInt($j("#qtyUpdateBox input").val());
    var customer_id = null;

    <?php if (isset($customer_id)) {?>
        customer_id = <?=$customer_id?>;
        //$j('#vendorPriceListHeading').css({
            //'width': '230px',
            //'margin-left':'105px',
            //'margin-right':'-80px'
        //  });
    <?php }?>

    if (qty==1){
        function sendRequestOne(i) {
            var optionSelectionArray = currentlySelectedAttributes(IDs[i]);

            simpleWithAttrPrice(optionSelectionArray, customer_id, qty, function(data) {
                var data= JSON.parse(data);
                var unitPrice = parseFloat(roundDollar(data.basePrice));

                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .priceBlock').empty();      
                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+formatCurrency(unitPrice,"$")+'</span>');

                $j('.details'+IDs[i]+ ' .vendorCheck input[name="customPrice"]:checked').val(unitPrice);
            });
        }//end sendRequest

        for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
        {   
            sendRequestOne(i);
        }

    }//end if
    else{
        //ajax call to obtain tier prices for each vendor id
        function sendRequest(i,qty,product_id){
            var vendor = IDs[i]; 
            $j.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax_calls/updatePrices.php",
                    async:false,
                    data: { 'vendorID': vendor, 'product_id': product_id}
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        //CAITLIN below may need to be parsed in the php script
                            var data= JSON.parse(data);

                            var optionSelectionArray = currentlySelectedAttributes(vendor);

                            simpleWithAttrPrice(optionSelectionArray, customer_id, qty, function(price) {
                                var price= JSON.parse(price);
                                var unitPrice = roundDollar(parseFloat(price.basePrice));
                                var pricexQty= unitPrice * qty;


                                if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){
                                    var unitPrice = totalPrice/qty;
                                }
                                else if (qty >= data.tier2_range_start && qty < data.tier3_range_start){
                                    var discountPercent = data.tier2_discount;
                                    var discount = pricexQty * data.tier2_discount / 100;
                                    var totalPrice = pricexQty - discount;
                                }
                                else if (qty >= data.tier3_range_start && qty < data.tier4_range_start){
                                    var discountPercent = data.tier3_discount;
                                    var discount = pricexQty * data.tier3_discount / 100;
                                    var totalPrice = pricexQty - discount;
                                }
                                else if (qty >= data.tier4_range_start && qty < data.tier5_range_start){
                                    var discountPercent = data.tier4_discount;
                                    var discount = pricexQty * data.tier4_discount / 100;
                                    var totalPrice = pricexQty - discount;
                                }
                                else if (qty >= data.tier5_range_start){
                                    var discountPercent = data.tier5_discount;
                                    var discount = pricexQty * data.tier5_discount / 100;
                                    var totalPrice = pricexQty - discount;
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log('Something went wrong');
                                }
                                var unitPrice = roundDollar(totalPrice/qty); //unitPrice including Shipping

                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    //BELOW IS LOGGING UNDEFINED SOMETIMES, BUT AJAX RESPONSE HAS THE VALUES
                                    console.log("The unit price is " + unitPrice + " and the discount percent is " + discountPercent);

                                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').empty();//update product price in DOM
                                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+formatCurrency(unitPrice,"$")+'</span>');
                                    //$j('.details'+data.vendor_id+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>Total Price: '+formatCurrency(unitPrice*qty,"$")+'</span>');
                                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .vendorCheck input[name="customPrice"]:checked').val(unitPrice);
                                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<h5 style="color:green">You will save '+discountPercent+'% !</h5>');
                                },1000);
                        });//end callback function

                        //reorderByPrice();

                    });//end done function
                }//end function sendRequest

        for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
        {   
            sendRequest(i,qty,product_id);
        }
    }//end else


    if (callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1);
    }
}//end function 



function simpleWithAttrPrice(optionSelectionArray, customer_id, qty, callback){
    var product_id= <?=$product_id ?>;

        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_calls/obtainBasePrice.php",
            data: { 'productID': product_id, 'optionSelectionArray' : optionSelectionArray, 'customer_id': customer_id, 'qty': qty} 
            }).done(callback);
}
```

Update Prices ajax call PHP:

```
<?php
$dbname='secret';
require_once('/connect.php');
require_once('/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app(); 
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("vendor");


//post variable
$ID= $_POST['vendorID'];
//$ID= 1497;
//echo 'the id is initially ' .$ID;

if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $ID= $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($ID);
    //echo $ID;
}
$product_id= $_POST['product_id'];
$echoArray= array();

if($ID == 3|| $ID ==4 || $ID ==11 || $ID ==12 || $ID ==13)
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tier_pricing WHERE vendor_id=' . $ID;
else
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tier_pricing WHERE vendor_id=' . $ID. ' AND product_id=' . $product_id;
    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
        $echoArray['vendor_id']= $row['vendor_id'];
            $echoArray['tier2_range_start']= $row['tier2_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier2_range_stop']= $row['tier2_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier3_range_start']= $row['tier3_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier3_range_stop']= $row['tier3_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier4_range_start']= $row['tier4_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier4_range_stop']= $row['tier4_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier5_range_start']= $row['tier5_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier2_discount']= $row['tier2_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier3_discount']= $row['tier3_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier4_discount']= $row['tier4_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier5_discount']= $row['tier5_discount'];
    }

echo json_encode($echoArray); 
?>
```

Response screen shot (all ajax calls are returning correct values):

[image: Console]
[image: Network]

Comment: I don't know I figured it would give it time to assign the value??? Just a feeble attempt. Same thing happens whether its there or not.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the problem, but you seem to be under the impression that javascript has block scope for your variables, [which it does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645073/java-vs-javascript-variable-scope).

Comment: This line: console.log("The unit price is " + unitPrice + " and the discount percent is " + discountPercent); has the correct values 90% of the time and has undefined the other 10% so I don't think thats the issue...

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the ajax request other than what the ajax request is returning.  What does `simpleWithAttrPrice` do?

Comment: I edited above with the function. Perhaps location of "    }
if (callback) {setTimeout(callback, 1);}"? I tried right before the timeout function but still getting undefined

Comment: Look at it this way. It is not possible for the console.log to happen before the ajax request is complete, and it is not possible for subsequent ajax requests to interfere with the request since you are properly declaring the variables and running the code in the done callback. If you are getting `undefined`, it's coming from the server's response. Also, i know you were doing this just for testing, but the `async: false` isn't needed.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is ever working... You aren't passing any arguments to the callback in `simpleWithAttrPrice`. I also don't see `customerId` or `qty` defined. Seems like this code should be throwing some errors.

Comment: You might also rethink this architecture; you have an ajax call which makes another ajax call. Could you possibly combine these into one call? That would certainly simplify things and make debugging easier

Comment: Would be better if you can to place code to the http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @cfs I didn't post the whole function. Just edited. See above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ycZfD/

Comment: @CaitlinHavener please, give us url `"/ajax_calls/updatePrices.php"` with your domain

Comment: if the ID is 3,4,11,12,or 13 you aren't actually executing the query and returning the data which would result in undefined, if i'm reading that correctly.

Comment: For each ajax request I am showing correct values in the network response in the network developer tab

Comment: See the screenshots I posted above. The console one, I ran the function three times. The last time I get undefined values. I click into the network tab as you can see at the bottom, and all of the requests have responses as they should.

Comment: Is the request you selected one of the ones that was showing NaN and Undefined?

Comment: Yes, or at least I checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying it works fine 90% of the time so i assume 90% of the time this `if` block is not get executed and its get executed other 10% of the time

```
if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){
   var unitPrice = totalPrice/qty;
}
```

If this block gets executed and than if you try to log using this line

```
console.log("The unit price is " + unitPrice + " and the discount percent is " + discountPercent);
```

At this point `discountPercent` is `undefined` because you are not calculating it in the first `if` block

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction! Changed that block to if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){var totalPrice = pricexQty;} and needed to skip displaying discount if there wasn't one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the `for` generates too many request to your server. Therefore the server response is may be not 200. You should look for the attribute `error` of the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and catch response thereafter you cat try move `setTimeout(...) ...` to the `error` section.

Comment: If it were resulting in error, the success callback wouldn't be happening and undefined wouldn't be getting logged to the console.